# Ajax data - Paginação

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, paginação

Estive estudando a documentação jquery e sobre ajax. Estou tentando entender como as requisições ajax e php trabalham.

Estou tentando transformar uma paginação normal em paginação ajax.

Mais especificamente como que eu uso o ajax `data` e trabalho com isso no servidor.

Da forma que tentei, no console esta retornando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em cada um dos numeros da paginação aparece o status 200 ok no console, e o numero correspondente de cada link, mas não muda nada na tela fica sempre no conteúdo do primeiro numero da paginação.

**AJAX**

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = "unidade.php"
   var page = $(this).attr('href');

   $.ajax({
         type:"get",
         url: url,
         data: {
            currentPage: page
         },  
         success: function (response) {

           var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
           $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )    


         }
   });
})
```

**class.crud.php**

```
public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);

            $current_page=1;



            if(isset($_GET["currentPage"]))
            {
                $current_page= $_GET["currentPage"];



            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a  class='page-link' href='1'>First</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$previous."'>Back</a></li>";

            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo $current_page;
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a  class='page-link' href='".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {

                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a  class='page-link' href='".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            ?></ul><?php
        }
    }
```

Agradeço ajuda

Answer (score 0):

O que seu *ajax* esta fazendo é chamar a página `unidade.php` e passar como parâmetro a variável `currentPage`, se não tiver uma chamada na página `unidade.php` o código da página `class.crud.php` **nunca** será executado.

Comment: mas na pagina unidade.php dentro da tag table tem o `id="paginacao-ajax"`

Comment: unidade.php [link](https://github.com/GihGis/pagination/blob/master/unidade.php) e class.crud.php [link](https://github.com/GihGis/pagination/blob/master/class.crud.php) por favor de uma olhada nos dois arquivos